# How to regex extract something from a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have this line:

```
[1] "RPKM_AB123_Gm12878_control.extended.bed_28m_control_500 and RPKM_AB156_GM12878-50ng_test.extended.bed_28m_test_500"
```

and I want to extract `AB123_Gm12878_control` and `AB156_GM12878-50ng` from the string.

I have tried this and it isn't working yet.

```
if ($_ =~ /.*"RPKM_([\w.]+).extended.+\s\w+\sRPKM_([\w.]+).extended.+"/){
   print $1,"\t",$2,"\t";
}
```

Can someone point out where I did it wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
".*RPKM_([\w.]+).extended.+\s\w+\sRPKM_([\w.]+).extended.+"
                                        ^^^^^
```

This character class is not accepting `-` which the string your matching against contains.

Try putting the hyphen in:

```
".*RPKM_([\w.]+)\.extended.+\s\w+\sRPKM_([\w.-]+)\.extended.+"
```

Also, it's good to escape the periods.

Comment: The periods, on the other hand, should probably *not* be in the charclasses.

Comment: @amon Probably. No idea whether the OP has strings where the parts to be extracted contain these...

Comment: Also, about the period, in this particular case I don't need to include period in the final output. I read somewhere that they don't escape period.Is it necessary to escape it?

Comment: @user2157668 It's safer to, so you don't end up with unexpected results!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify regex and match all occurrences using `/g`

```
if ( my($m1, $m2) = /RPKM_([^.]+)/g ) {
  print $m1,"\t",$m2,"\t";
}
```